# How to select element which comes with axios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, axios

I'm trying to select element which comes from http request with axios

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://example.com/')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Response is looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img class="image" src="example.png" alt="example">
            <div class="col">Example</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i.e. I want to select `.image`'s src attribute.

I want to select an element in `response`. It would be great if we can do it with jQuery. I want to access its attribute, and html content.

Comment: Ciao, how the `response` looks like?

Comment: @sundowatch your missing some keys in your question, you write `I want to select an element in response.` but what element? Let's say it's the image, have you tried `$(response).find(".image")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've edited it

Comment: @sundowatch then you can use `$(response).find(".image")`

Comment: is response a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server)

```
 axios
   .get(url)
   .then(response => {
     const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

     const image = $('img')
 
     $("img").each((i, elem) => {
       {
          ...
       })
     ...
   })
```

Comment: I think you're right to use cheerio, instead of jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you add the response to the document and then try to get event then you can try the following method

```
$('body').on('click', '.col', function(){
    // do your work
})
```

if you want to select any element on the fly then use the following method

```
$(response).find('.col')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, look this example:

```js
console.log($( "div.col" ).text())
console.log($( "img" ).attr('src'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="example.png" alt="example">
            <div class="col">Example</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the inner text of div `col` with `$( "div.col" ).text()`.

To get an attribute (for example `src` of `img`) I have done `$( "img" ).attr('src')`

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my axios call:

```
axios.get( fullurl, {responseType: 'document'} );
```

The response will come back as a HTML Document.

With the response data returned as HTML document, you can then use a querySelector to get the image class like this:

```
const allHTML = response.data;
let getImage = allHTML.querySelector('.image');
```

With this method you won't need to use any additional libraries.